# Hashtag generator function - check to see if string matches requirements

Tags: javascript

The function `generateHashtag(str);` is passed a string that must meet the following criteria:

1. If the final result is longer than 140 chars it must return false.
2. If the input is a empty string it must return false.
3. It must start with a hashtag (#).
4. All words must have their first letter capitalized.

**Example Input to Output:**

" Hello there thanks for trying my Kata" => "#HelloThereThanksForTryingMyKata"

" Hello World " => "#HelloWorld"

Here is my code so far:

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
    if (!str) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var los = str.toLowerCase();
        var res = los.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
    } 

    if ( res.charAt( 0 ) != '#' ) { 
        res = "# " + res;
    } else {
        res = "" + res;
    }

    if (res.length > 140) {
        return false; 
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

This is a coding challenge from the codewar.com site. I get the following message there `Test didn't pass: Unknown error`. It works on js fiddle [link to js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0m6bcq6/)

Comment: Looks like you aren't replacing whitespace characters.  Have you tried adding a regex like `/\s/g` or similar to replace the spaces?  You're also adding a space at the begging by using `res = "# " + res;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
function generateHashtag (str) {
  if(!str || str.length == 0 || (str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z\s])/g, "").length + 1) > 140)
    return false;

  var finalString = "";
  str = str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z\s])/g, "").trim().toLowerCase().split(" ");

  for(i in str)
    finalString += str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1);

  return "#" + finalString;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c0m6bcq6/1/